# How to link tagged headlines in an org-mode table?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using tags quite extensively in org-mode.
Now I want to create a mapping table as following:

```
| Name  | Headlines  |
|-------+------------| 
| Nico  | <all headlines tagged with :nico: |
| aaa   | <all headlines tagged with :aaa: |
```

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this programmatically? Manually I can search for all headlines matching the tags, manually I can create a table - but how do I link both together?

This should not be just a search / view, because the actual table contains more elements:

```
| Name  | Field1 | Field2 | Headlines  |
|-------+------------| 
| Nico  | ..     |  ..    | <all headlines tagged with :nico: |
| aaa   | ..     |  ..    | <all headlines tagged with :aaa: |
```

Any hints in the right direction are appreciated.

A bit more background information on why doing this:

I have a lot of tasks that are tagged and I'd like to summarise the tasks of specific tags in that table.

Additionally I have some information that is related to the tag overall, not to a specific task that is tagged.

One of the use cases is to handle delegation of tasks to other members of our team. So the tag is equal to a team member.
Let's say we have members Toni, Julia and Nico. I would like to summarise all tasks in that table, but also be able to add a comment. For instance Julia is on holidays, so I do not need to update her tasks. Or I need to dispatch some of her tasks to Toni instead.

In reality, the Field2 in my description is the working percentage of the team member (10h/week...40h/week) - which allows me to easily see how fast the tasks could in theory progress.

If there is a different solution to have a overview with per tag "comments" / structured data (maybe using PROPERTIES?), that could also be a solution.

Hope that explains the motivation/what I want to achieve a bit better.

Comment: What do you expect on the "Headlines" column? Is it a link to activate a sparse tree match? Or is it actually many rows with links to each matching headline?

Comment: I'd expect the headline itself - does not even have to be linked (would be nice if it was).